# Prove convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I need help with the following problem.

Let $X_{n1}, X_{n2}, . . . , X_{nn}$ be independent random variables, with the same distribution as follows.
Let for k = 1, 2, . . . , n och n = 1, 2, . . . ,
$$P(X_{nk} = 0) = 1 −
\frac{2}{n}
−
\frac{4}{n^3}$$
$$P(X_{nk} = 1) = \frac{2}{n}$$
$$P(X_{nk} = 2) = \frac{4}{n^3}$$
and $S_n =\sum^n_{k=1} X_{nk}$.

Show that
$Sn
→ P o(λ)$ when $n → ∞$
and determine $λ$.

I was thinking of using $G_{s_n}(t)=G_N(G_X(t))$

I got that $G_X(t)=1-\frac{2}{n}(1+t)+\frac{4}{n^3}(t^2-1)$

I don't know if this is the correct approach and if it is I don't know how to continue from here. How do I then find $G_N(t)$

Anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

1) $X\sim  Po(\lambda) \iff \mathbb{E}\left[\exp(tX)\right]{}={}\exp(\lambda(e^t-1))$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$;

2) Independent and identically distributed random variables $X, X_1,\ldots,X_n$, imply 
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{t\sum\limits^{n}_{i{}={}1}X_i}\right]{}={}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[e^{tX}\right]\right)^n\,;
$$

3) $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1{}+{}c/n{}+{}o(1/n)  \bigg)^n{}={}e^c$.

Comment: @LazyStupidGuy, I don't. I am simply saying that, if you want to show that a random variable is Poisson distributed, it is enough to show that the random variable has a moment generating function that looks like the moment generating function for a Poisson distribution. So, in your attempt, you hunch was correct to look at Moment generating functions. And, on that note, please recalculate your expression for $G_X(t)$; remember that it is $\mathbb{E}[\exp^{(tX)}]$. Then, use the hints to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\exp^{(tS_n)}]$.

Comment: My mistake! Understand what you mean.

@ki3i 

The problem was that I used probability generating functions ($E[t^X]$) instead of moment generating ones.

thanks alot!

Comment: @LazyStupidGuy, That makes sense; so a simple substitution should suffice to go from "probability" to "moment". Glad to have helped you answer the question.